# Uploading multiple images with Alamofire causes huge memory usage

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am working on an app that we need to upload multiple images to our server using Alamofire. The problem is converting UIImage to Data then appending it to Multipart uses so much memory and eventually causes app to crash.

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipart) in

    for (key, value) in endpoint.params {
        if let images = value as? [UIImage] {
            for i in 0..<images.count {
                if let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(images[i], 0.6) {
                    multipart.append(data, withName: "\(key)\(i)", fileName: "note.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, usingThreshold: UInt64.init(),
   to: endpoint.path,
   method: endpoint.method,
   headers: endpoint.headers, 
   encodingCompletion: {...}
```

Some people advised using a stream but couldn't find an example. How can I fix the issue?

Comment: Can u show the memory usage graph? Does the memory usage go up and then come back down, or does the memory stay used? Try enclosing your for loop in `autoreleasepool { }` block.

Comment: @BadhanGanesh I tried enclosing it in autoreleasepool but didn't effect anything. Here is the memory usage graph: https://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2017/09/21/EkranResmi2017-09-2114.49.10.png